# how to generate graph bar in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am newbie in codeignitner. Anyone know how to generate a graph bar in codeigniter. I wan to generate the data based on the data in the mysql database.Any example coding can provide me to refer?thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the library to do that, you can put that in Application\Libraries or Application\Helpers (if your library is procedural)

Comment: What should i put in the Application\Libraries or Application\Helpers.There are nothing inside except one index file.I have no idea at all in generating the graph bar in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **JpGraph** with codeigniter and it is really good. It is simple and easy to use.

You can have all information in [JpGraph.net](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto.php)